# Maven multilevel plugin inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, plugins, maven-plugin

I have project structure in which I have inheritance relation:

parent-pom1(spring-boot-starter-parent) <- parent-pom2(my-common-dependencies) <- child-pom(my-project)

**parent-pom1** contains *pluginManagement* section with plugin with predefined configuration:

```xml
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <id>common-plugin</id>
      <configuration>
        <!--Some config-->
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

In **parent-pom2** I want to redefine plugin configuration:

```xml
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <id>common-plugin</id>
      <configuration>
        <!--Different config-->
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

But **child-pom** ignores configuration found in **parent-pom2** and reads the one in **parent-pom1**.
Is there a way to override that behavior?

Comment: This article explains how configuration inheritence works and how you can control it: https://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/

Comment: @RobertScholte thx for answer. I read this article previously. Maybe I will describe what I want to do. Spring-boot-parent is forcing me some plugin configuration via pluginManagement. My Parent POM inherits from spring-boot-parent. I would like to override this configuration in it, in such a way that all my other modules (inheriting from my Parent POM) will by default execute this plugin with overridden configuration.

Comment: Better make a small example (e.g. in github) to show your issue, as there's not enough info to reproduce and understand your issue. Did you move the configuration to the specific excecution block?